# Queryset is returned inside children key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I wanted to list all the reviews along with the replies to specific review of specific restaurant but i could only list the review. While trying to fetch all the replies to its specific review, i called the children() which is defined in Review model. It returned queryset. On the other hand i want all the specific replies with the name of replier.

**serializers.py**

```
class ReviewSeraializer(ModelSerializer):
    reply_count = SerializerMethodField()
    children = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        read_only = ('id',) 
        fields = ('id','content_type','object_id','parent','review','children','reply_count','created') 

    def get_reply_count(self, obj):
        if obj.is_parent:
            return obj.children().count()
        return 0

    def get_children(self, obj):
        obj_children = []
        if obj.is_parent:
            return str(obj.children())
            # for obj in obj.children():
            #   print(obj.review)
            #   obj_children.append(obj.review)
            # return str(obj_children)
        return None
```

**review/models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, related_name="parent_review")
    review = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = ReviewManager()


    def children(self): # replies
        return Review.objects.filter(parent=self)

    @property   
    def is_parent(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return False 
        return True
```

[image]

How to list all the replies and replier name inside children key of a specific review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another serializer that can serialize your children.

```
class ReviewSeraializerChild(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Review


class ReviewSeraializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reply_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    children = ReviewSeraializerChild(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        read_only = ('id',)
        fields = ('id', 'content_type', 'object_id', 'parent', 'review', 'children', 'reply_count', 'created')

    def get_reply_count(self, obj):
        if obj.is_parent:
            return obj.children().count()
        return 0
```

But you must write your custom create() and update() functions for nested fields[image].

Comment: Posting comment is working and also replies. Also using django template i could fetch the replies of a specific review but I have only problem of fetching replies of a specific review using reactjs and api. I will try with this method now.

Comment: Check https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers. You can create nested routes and it will be easier manage your reviews api with reactJS.